# Linux on-exit (Ctrl-C) action

Tags: bash, events

This is an interesting scenario and I'm relatively new in writing shell scripts.  I have a case where I want the user to enter a password at a prompt.  That works fine.

The PROBLEM is if the user should `Ctrl-C` exit at that point.  Because the password prompt turns off text entry to the terminal, if the users exits there, text entry to the terminal is still turned off, leaving a frustrated user.

In PHP programming we have a `register_shutdown_function()` which will be called on exit, regardless of where or when that happens in the program.  Is there an equivalent in Bash for the `Ctrl-C` command?

Comment: Are you using `read -s` or are you turning echo off/on yourself?

Comment: "/usr/bin/env bash -c 'read -s -p \""
                . addslashes($prompt)
                . "\" mypassword && echo \$mypassword'"

Comment: Please put it into your question, where you can format it more easily with `{}`. It's also better there because everyone can quickly find it as part of your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `bash` has the `trap` builtin.

```
trap 'stty echo'  EXIT
```

Documented in `man bash`.